# Ubuntu Touch: automatic update to version 16

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am using Ubuntu Touch on BQ 4.5. 
For Updates I chose never to allow automatic updates.

The more I was surprised to see, that my phone claims to have updated the operating system to version 16 today (december 30th).

I didn't find any information on what this update contains nor why it was forced.

Is there any information on this out there?

Comment: The newest version you can get through normal updates is currently OTA-14 (based on vivid 15.04).

Comment: I want to know what this is, too. My MX4 was also updated to version 16. My M10 was updated to version 7...

Comment: Can,t belive that your device has upgraded to Ubintu 16. Would you please provide a screenshot of the 'about' section?

Comment: I cant upload a screenshot here. In the about section it is still the old ota 14.